# Passing indices of a 3D array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

[Here](http://cpp.sh/9ozd) is my full code thus far, in case you want to reference it.

So I have a 3D array storing high and low temperatures for given days/months. I need to pass the array through this function:

```
double average_array(int A[], int SIZE)
{
    int total=0;
    double avg;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        total = total + A[i];
    }

    avg = (double) total / (double) SIZE;   
    return avg;
}
```

I've tried things like

```
for (i=0; i<DAY; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<TEMP; k++)
            {
                cout << "The average for June was " << average_array(array[i][0], 3) << endl;
            }
    } break;
```

to get only the average for June, or even

```
for (i=0; i<DAY; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<MONTH; j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<TEMP; k++)
        {
            cout << "The average was " << average_array(array[i][j][k],3) << endl;
        }
    }
} break;
```

to try printing the overall average. The former prints nothing (though compiles just fine), while the latter returns "error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]"

How do I pass the appropriate indices of my array through the function?

Comment: What is you array meant to represent? [Day][Month][Temp]=???

Comment: I've never seen anyone put a `break` statement after the last paren of a for loop block. What exactly are you intending that to do?

Comment: `average_array(array[i][0], TEMP)` would calculate the average for day `i` of month `0`. Is that what you want? (If not then I'm not clear on what you want). It would help to clearly state which calculations you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrEricSir these are inside of a huge switch statement, hence the `break`.

@Matt McNabb yes, assuming that the month June is at index 0. Then for July I would have `array[i][1]`. For this example I am calculating the average temperature for month June.   
`TEMP` does not belong there either, however I don't know what else to feed argument 2. The function wants `SIZE` for argument 2. I would think that size is `DAY`, except I am already feeding the function the number of days by iterating `i`.  
Clearly I don't know what I am doing. I seriously appreciate all of these replies!

Answer (score 0):

If array is `array` is `double array[MONTH][DAY][TEMP];`

```
for (i=0; i<MONTH; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<DAY; j++)
    {
        cout << "The average was " << average_array(&array[i][j][0],TEMP) << endl;
// or average_array(array[i][j],TEMP)
    }
}
```